# EJB datasource JNDI name not found (RemoteException)

Tags: ejb, datasource, jndi

The datasource JNDI name is not found and it throws a RemoteException. The JNDI-name is specified in the deployment tool and it is in the deployment descriptor/xml-file:

```
<resource-ref>               
<res-ref-name>jdbc/TargetDB</res-ref-name>                
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>                
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>                
<res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>            
</resource-ref>
```

The code that tries to find the JNDI name:

```
  InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext();
  DataSource ds = (DataSource)jndiContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/TargetDB"); 
  return ds.getConnection();
```

And the stack trace after execution:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.RemoteException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/jdbc/TargetDB
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:830)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:763)
    org.apache.jsp.GetSports_jsp._jspService(GetSports_jsp.java:94)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:105)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:860)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:297)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:247)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:860)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:249)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:165)
root cause

java.lang.Exception: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.RemoteException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/jdbc/TargetDB
    org.apache.jsp.GetSports_jsp._jspService(GetSports_jsp.java:77)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:105)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:860)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:297)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:247)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:860)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:249)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:165)
```

What goes wrong?

Comment: did you initialize the InitialContext properties? if not, what is the JBoss version?

Comment: I did not initialize the InitialContext. I'm using the server that comes with j2ee sdk 1_4_03.

Comment: are you aware that this is a very old version? just for curiosity, why are you using it?

Comment: actually I was not aware of that. Im just starting out developing j2ee apps and it seems I had downloaded some old version. Im now moving to use the latest sdk with netbeans ide.